# Why are there $k$ permutations having $\sigma(k)$ being the largest of the first $k$ elements in $\sigma(\cdot)$ here?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

I am confused about the following answer to this question:

> For a fixed $1 \leq k \leq n$, how many permutations $\sigma$ of 1 through $n$ are there where for all $i<k, \sigma(i)<$ $\sigma(k)$ ? Express your answers in terms of $n$ and $k$.
> **Answer**: $n! \over k$, as $1 \over k$ of the permutations have $\sigma(k)$ being the largest of the first $k$ elements in $\sigma(\cdot)$.

What is the justification behind saying that there are $k$ permutations having $\sigma(k)$ being the largest of the first $k$ elements in $\sigma(\cdot)$?

EDIT:
Is this reasoning correct? For every way of partitioning the $n$ elements into groups of size $k$ and $n-k$ respectively, if we consider the number of permutations such that the first $k$ elements constitute the group of size $k$ in the partition, there are $(k-1) ! \cdot (n-k)!$ ways to order the elements if the $k$ th element is the largest amongst the first $k$ (as in the first group we order the $k-1$ elements after the $k$ th element is fixed)- but all permutations with this partitioning is $k ! \cdot (n-k)$ ! which is $k$ times as much?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\tau$ be the permutation that cyclically permutes the first $k$ elements and fixes the other $n-k$. For any $\sigma$ whatsoever, check that of the $k$ permutations $\sigma$, $\tau\circ\sigma$, $\tau^2\circ\sigma$, ..., $\tau^{k-1}\circ\sigma$, exactly one of them has the property that the $k$th element is larger than all of the first $k-1$.

Comment: Would you be able to translate this in more informal terms actually? I am unfamiliar with this terminology and the notion of permutations as functions was introduced by the question I was working on and not taught to me in my classes

Comment: Would this suffice as an informal argument? For every way of partitioning the $n$ elements into groups of size $k$ and $n-k$ respectively, if we consider the number of permutations such that the first $k$ elements constitute the group of size $k$ in the partition, there are $(k-1)!*(n-k)!$ ways to order the elements if the $k$th element is the largest  amongst the first $k$ (as in the first group we order the $k-1$ elements after the $k$th element is fixed)- but all permutations with this partitioning is $k!*(n-k)!$ which is $k$ times as much?

Comment: That's a pretty decent explanation!